# How can I transfer a file across 2 servers (source->serverA->serverB) with a single script.

Tags: scp, autologin

I have 3 linux servers - the first one is a dev machine (where I compile my binary), the second one is a "jumpbox" which helps me connect to a "testbed" - which is the place where I need to copy my binary.

Right now, I am doing something like this:

1) Copy my binary from devmachine to jumpbox with scp -r binary abc@jumpbox:/temp/

2) Log in to the jumpbox and copy the binary from jumpbok to testbed with scp -r binary abc@testbed:/bin/

Is there some way I can do the above 2 steps thru a single script?

I realize I will be forced to save my passwords in a file for that to work, but I am fine with it - I can always use encryption.

Comment: just a question, can source reach directly serverB ? if yes the question is a bit pointless.

Comment: No it cannot ..

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option would be, to perform a ssh connection [without password via pubkey authentication](http://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/). That means you have to share the public keys between the servers.

Then you can just use a command like that at the "source" server:

```
cat file | ssh user@serverA "ssh user@serverB \"cat > file\""
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to set up a password less login, using public/private key with ssh.

then, assuming fles to be copied are in `dir`,

```
source$ tar cf - dir | ssh servera 'ssh serverb "cd dest ; tar xf - " '
```

where

- `source$` is you prompt
- `tar cf - dir` tar files in dir to stdin
- `ssh servera` logs you to servera
- `cd dest ; tar xf -`  extract from stdin files in dest dir.

Comment: I was wondering If ssh could be used with port forwarding deom source to server A, then using rsync between source and serverB.